# Accessing the test interface shutdown callback method inside the DUT class?

Tags: origen-sdk

Is it possible to access the same shutdown method found in the test interface within the DUT class?  I see the test program generation callbacks [here](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/misc/callbacks/#program_generation) but none of them get to the end of the Origen generation command.  We would like to be able to do this without having to point the Gemfile at a local path for the test interface gem and setting a breakpoint there.

```
# This will be called at the end of every flow or sub-flow (at the end of every
# Flow.create block).
# Any options passed to Flow.create will be passed in here.
# The options will contain top_level: true, whenever this is called at the end of a
# top-level flow file.
def shutdown(options = {})
  binding.pry
  # Write the tests disabled/removed to the .tf file
  render "\n"
  [:defined, :enabled, :disabled, :removed].each do |category|
    test_list = Origen.top_level.test_modules(options[:test_module]).send("tests_#{category}".to_sym)
    render "-- #{category.to_s.capitalize} test count: #{test_list.size}"
    unless test_list.empty?
      render "-- #{category.to_s.capitalize} Tests: #{test_list.to_csv}" if category.smatch(/remove|disable/)
    end
  end
```

The existing ['on_flow_end' callback](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/misc/callbacks/#on_flow_end(options)) is not equivalent to the 'shutdown' callback in the test interface shown above.

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no automatic hookup for that, but it's easy enough to implement in your application:

```rb
# my/interface.rb

def shutdown(options = {})
  dut.some_shutdown_method
end
```

You may also consider the on_origen_shutdown callback if you want to target the very end of the Origen generate command:
http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/misc/callbacks/#Environment_Teardown